# textview.getPaint() got error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21" "Error inflating class fragment"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to Android studio. I am trying to set a style for a TextView in a Fragment, but got errors. "Error inflating class fragment" "Binary XML file line #21". Thank you for your help!

```
TextView textview= (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textview);
EmbossMaskFilter embossmaskfilter = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[]{1,5,1}, // direction of the light source
                0.5f, // ambient light between 0 to 1
                10, // specular highlights
                7.5f); // blur before applying lighting);
textview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
textview.getPaint().setMaskFilter(embossmaskfilter);
```

Answer (score -1):

`Error inflating class fragment` `Binary XML file line #21` means that the error is in your XML-File, not in your code. Most probably when you look at the XML-Layout-File of the fragment in Line 21 you will find something that does not work.

Comment: why did you downvote if the answer helped you? You should mark as the solution and if you liked it upvote.